# Singular homogeneous polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $p$ be a homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{K}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$,
where $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraically closed field. If $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}$
vanishes on the vanishing set of $p$, 
is it true that $p$ is a product of linear forms?

Answer (score 2):

No: take $n=3$, $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb K)=5$  and $p=y^{10}z^{5}-x^{15}= (y^2z-x^3)^5$ .

**More general counterexamples**
Over any field $k$, of any characteristic, algebraically closed or not, take a homogeneous irreducible polynomial $f\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ of degree at least $2$.
Then $p=f^2$ (or any higher power of $f$) will give a counterexample.

**Remark**
Over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$ of any characteristic it is impossible that all the partial derivatives $\frac {\partial p}{\partial x_i}$  of an irreducible polynomial $p$ vanish on $V(p)$, the vanishing locus of $p$.
This is the geometric fact that the singularities of the variety $V(p)\subset \mathbb P^{n-1}$ form a strict closed subset $\operatorname {Sing}V(p)\subsetneq V(p)$ of that variety: Hartshorne page 33.